# Merging Corresponding MySQL Records

Tags: mysql, merge, duplicates

I have a MySQL table called "objecttable" that has the following structure and data in it. (The data is just a sequence, there is a whole lot more).

```
ID    |  Name              |  posX  |  posY   | posZ |rotX | rotY | rotZ | rotW  |  
3562  |   LODpmedhos1_LAe  |  2062  |  -1703  |  16  |  0  |  45  |  22  |  1    |  
3559  |   LODpmedhos5_LAe  |  2021  |  -1717  |  15  |  0  |  45  |  34  |  1    |  
3561  |   LODpmedhos3_LAe  |  2021  |  -1717  |  15  |  0  |  45  |  34  |  1    |
```

I want to figure out which records have the same posX, posY, posZ, rotX, rotY and rotZ values and insert them into a table called "matchtable", and in the end I want it to look like this (I have the table structure ready)

```
ID1     |       Name            |   ID2     |   Name          |  
3559    |   LODpmedhos5_LAe     |   3561    |  LODpmedhos3_LAe|
```

I'd appreciate if someone could give me the correct SQL query for it. I don't have more than two matching coordinates and not all coordinates match.

Sorry if the table representations suck, I'll try to make a HTML table if necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: All the SQL queries I tried were those I found here on StackExchange and none worked, I'm afraid it's like I didn't try anything. No idea which way to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

This query will do the trick, but the number of results might be a LOT more than required. For example, if there are *5 rows* satisfying your query, then the results will be **20( = n*(n-1) )** in number.

```
SELECT ot.ID AS ID1, ot.Name AS Name1, ot2.ID AS ID2, ot2.Name AS Name
FROM objecttable ot
JOIN objecttable ot2
    ON ot.ID > ot2.ID
        AND ot.posX = ot2.posX
        AND ot.posY = ot2.posY
        AND ot.posZ = ot2.posZ
        AND ot.rotX = ot2.rotX
        AND ot.rotY = ot2.rotY
        AND ot.rotZ = ot2.rotZ
```

## EDIT

In reply to [lserni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1428679/lserni)'s comment:

```
ON ot.ID <> ot2.ID
```

The above condition is there to remove the result like:

```
ID1     |       Name            |   ID2     |   Name          |
3559    |   LODpmedhos5_LAe     |   3559    |  LODpmedhos5_LAe|
```

Comment: Seems like it works, but I don't get what this is supposed to mean:

For example, if there are 5 rows satisfying your query, then the results will be 20( = n*(n-1) ) in number.

Comment: @Funstein Let's suppose there was a third row too, which had same conditions as with your `ID = 3559`, then total number of rows generated would be **6** following the *Permutation* of `3P2`.

Comment: Er, shouldn't the match be on *equal* coordinates? That query there looks like it searches for objects that *do not* match...

Comment: Yes, but I was referring to the other conditions. `ot.posX <> ot2.posX` will return those records where coordinates differ, and the OP wanted those records where coordinates match (and IDs don't).

Comment: @lserni ohh! copy paste FAIL!

Comment: OK, now one last thing. If you have two records A and B in the same position, your query will return both (A,B) and (B,A) since <> doesn't set an ordering. You need to have either `ot.ID < ot2.ID` or `ot.id > ot2.ID`.

Comment: Even in that case, the results shall be half of `nP(n-1)`. But yeah, that's twice better result set. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
-- insert into matchtable -- uncomment to insert the data
select alias1.Id,
    alias1.Name, 
    alias2.Id
    alias2.Name
from objecttable as alias1
    join objecttable as alias2
        on alias1.posx = alias2.posx
            and alias1.posy = alias2.posy
            and alias1.posz = alias2.posz
            and alias1.roty = alias2.roty
            and alias1.roty = alias2.roty
            and alias1.rotz = alias2.rotz
            and alias1.Id > alias2.Id
```

Comment: Which "tablename" should I replace with the name of which table? I have included the tables' names in the original post, can you edit the solution according to them?

Comment: AFAIK, that won't work. ^_^ You still haven't defined `alias1` or `alias2`.

Comment: sorry, i changed the alias instead of the table name :-) i corrected this